# Arguments were passed wrong in pthread

Tags: linux, multithreading, parameters, pthreads, arguments

I write a code to print out strings: "Thread 0" to "Thread 4" using pthread.

Here is my code:

### Case 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *print_message_function(void* parameter) {
    long *i = (long *)parameter;
    printf("Thread %ld\n", *i);
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t threads[5];
    long i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], 0, print_message_function, (void *)&i);
    }
    
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

But the result is:

```
Thread 2
Thread 3
Thread 3
Thread 4
Thread 5
```

or:

```
Thread 0
Thread 0
Thread 0
Thread 0
Thread 0
```

It changed when I run it again. So I don't know why the values I passed are (2 to 5) or all (0) or ..... (many cases). I think my arguments I passed is from 0 to 4.

### **Case 2:**

When I change to the new code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *print_message_function(void *parameter);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t threads[5];
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        char *msg = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
        sprintf(msg, "Thread %d", i);
        pthread_create(&threads[i], 0, print_message_function, (void *)msg);
    }
}

void *print_message_function(void *parameter) {
    printf("%s\n", (char *)parameter);
}
```

The result is:

```
Thread 1
Thread 0
Thread 3
Thread 2
Thread 4
Thread 4
```

It means the loop run 6 times! Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change **Case 1** to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *print_message_function(void* parameter) {
    long i = (long)parameter;  // <<<
    printf("Thread %ld\n", i); // <<<
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t threads[5];
    long i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], 0, print_message_function, (void *)i); // <<<
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The reason that you were seeing inconsistent results before was because you were passing a pointer to each thread where each pointer was pointing at the same local variable, which you were then modifying.

In **Case 2** you are `malloc`ing only a single char and then trying to write a string to it. It should be fairly easy to fix.

Comment: Ah, I see in case 1. You're right! :). But in case 2, why the loop runs 6 times?

Comment: In case 2 anything can happen as you're stomping all over memory.

Comment: I want to ask you a question: If I use a struct instead of integer i, I can not to pass: (void*)struct_param. How can I fix this? I don't want to pass its address.

Comment: If the struct needs to be unique for each thread then you will need to create N instances of the struct which each have a sufficiently long lifetime. You would probably want to do this by `malloc`ing each struct in much the same way that you do for each string in **Case 2**. You would need to make sure that you `free` each struct when the thread terminates.

Answer (score 2):

Your *case 2* approach is valid, however you need to fix the `malloc` part to allocate enough bytes. Change it to

```
char *msg = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen("Thread ") + 10));
// assuming i will take at most 9-digits (unlikely case)
```

For your *case 1*, you are passing address of `i`. But the value of `i` is changing thread function will get whatever value is there at that location when it tries to print. Also note that address of `i` may not be valid by the time thread function executes as its allocated on stack and will go away when `main` function returns.